# DynamoDb : Accessing data By using findAllById(ids) is giving a exception

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

All,

We are using Java to connect to DynamoDb and get the data.

```
List<String> ids = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Device dv : uniques){

            ids.add(dv.getUId());
    }


List<DynamoTableData> uList =  userTableRepository.findAllById(ids);
```

But when we are getting issue while accessing the data.

could not invoke public void model.dynamodb.DynamoDBTable.setId(java.lang.String) on class model.dynamodb.DynamoDBTable with value [1,2, 4, 3,  3, of type class java.util.ArrayList"

What might be the possible issue?

Comment: `could not invoke public void model.dynamodb.DynamoDBTable.setId(java.lang.String) on class model.dynamodb.DynamoDBTable with value [1,2, 4, 3, 3, of type class java.util.ArrayList"` log clearly says,what is the issue

Comment: `for(String id: ids) {List<DynamoTableData> uList =  userTableRepository.findAllById(ids);}`

Comment: does your definition of  `findAllById` method has `(List<String> ids)`?